# Do letters matter on thermal fuses?

Tags: fuses, thermal, thermal-cutoff

DIY oven repair question.

I need to replace this thermal fuse:

[image: img]

Does it matter what letters there are shown i.e. `YCW.dz` `YCWRY`, `TF` etc. or I can just replace it with any which has similar specs (216 C, 10A- 250V) i.e. like [this example](https://dac.ge/en/?product=3580&category=28&subcategory=123)?

Comment: Is it an exact substitute? Have you checked the data sheets for both parts and compared them at the fine detail level?

Comment: @Andyaka that's point, I am not well-versed in electricity and have no clue what more details could be beyond 10A-250V-216C for thermal fuse. it's a simple appliance like https://imart.ge/images/detailed/107/W_60jj-24.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The key parameters for thermal fuses are:

- Limit temperature (+ tolerance)
- Upper operating voltage
- Upper operating current
- Auto-resetting (on temp reduction),  Latching (reset on temp reduction + power removal), manual reset, single shot / non-resetting
- hysterisis (if auto-reset)

As long as your replacement device matches on these, it will normally be fine, but to do this, you really need the datasheets for both new and old.

I would guess (but you should confirm) that the fact that you are looking to replace the fuse, means this is a non-resetting device, so as you suggest, key would be to match on the other parameters.